# How to allow only specified child names for write operation with Firebase Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an users node where I have user data which consists of uid, name and age only, like the following:

```
{
  "user_1": {
    "uid": "user_1",
    "name": "Alex",
    "age": 35,
  }
}
```

I thought that I could use the `hasChildren` method to prevent anyone from adding a child except the ones I specified:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['uid', 'name', 'age'])",
  },
}
```

However, it doesn't work because users can add anything they want as long as they provide uid, name and age. I always check the data on the client side, but someone malicious can figure out the api and add unnecessary stuff. Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing about this issue in the docs, but I was googling and found something. Including an additional wildcard in your node and making `.validate` always false rejects the operation when the new data has a key of a child other than the keys you specify.

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['uid', 'name', 'age'])",
    // Make sure you specify all keys you want to allow
    // so the wildcard won't match them
    "uid": { ".validate": "newData.isString()" },
    "name": { ".validate": "newData.isString()" },
    "age": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber()" },
    // Add this wildcard below and make it false always
    "$other": { ".validate": false }
  }
}
```

Don't forget that you should include all keys in the node.

Check [this](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/hcnWRc1Yliw/m/8XmVwcXhAwAJ) out for more.